# Javascript Unintentionally Changing Multiple Objects' Array Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, reference

I am running into a weird problem where I am trying to change the value of an attribute in a specific object it's changing that attribute value in all objects.

Below is my code the creates these objects "nodes"

```
function processNode(nodeID, name, fields){
    this.id =  nodeID;
    this.fields = fields;
    this.name = name;
}

var nodeFuncs = {table:
    function(nodeID){
        function tableNode() {}
        tableNode.prototype = Object.create(new terminalNode(nodeID, 'table'));
        return new tableNode(nodeID, 'table');
    }
    , source:
    function(nodeID){
        function sourceNode() {}
        sourceNode.prototype = Object.create(new processNode(nodeID, 'source'));
        sourceNode.prototype.table = '';
        sourceNode.prototype.selectors = '';
        sourceNode.prototype.include = 1;

        return new sourceNode(nodeID, 'source', []);
    }
    , sort:
    function(nodeID){
        function sortNode() {}
        sortNode.prototype = Object.create(new processNode(nodeID, 'sort'));
        sortNode.prototype.order = [];

        return new sortNode(nodeID, 'sort', [])
    }
    , filter:
    function(nodeID){
        function filterNode() {}
        filterNode.prototype = Object.create(new processNode(nodeID, 'filter'));
        filterNode.prototype.names = [];

        return new filterNode(nodeID, 'filter', [])
    }
}

function createNode(nodeID, name){
    return nodeFuncs[name](nodeID);
}

idToNodeObjectMap['abc123'] = createNode('abc123', 'source')
idToNodeObjectMap['abc124'] = createNode('abc124', 'sort')
idToNodeObjectMap['abc125'] = createNode('abc125', 'filter')
idToNodeObjectMap['abc126'] = createNode('abc126', 'filter')
```

Here is a sample jquery event that is triggering the re-valuing of an object's attribute:

```
$('body').on('click', "div button.ok", function(){
    var nodeID = $(this).parent('div.nodeForm').attr('id')
    var objectNode = idToNodeObjectMap[nodeID];
    objectNode.fields.splice(1,1);
});
```

For example I will have 4 objects and reference one of them as var objectNode whose .fields value is ['tid', 'gid', 'tname']. Then when I call objectNode.fields.splice(1,1) the .fields value will be ['tid', 'tname'] FOR ALL 4 OBJECTS not just the one that is reference in the objectNode variable.

BUT, when I change the line...
    objectNode.fields.splice(1,1);
to...
    objectNode.fields = ['hi'];
then it only changes the .fields attribute of the object that I referenced as var objectNode.

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen? I thought it might be a referencing issue where all .fields were referencing and changing each others values but that doesn't seem to make sense to me because when I set the .fields attribute equal to ['hi'] it only changes one object's .fields attribute.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If `objectNode.fields.splice(1, 1)` changes them all, then they are indeed all pointing to the same array.  `objectNode.fields = ['hi']` does not change all of them, because you are not changing the array that the fields is pointing to, you are changing **what** array this particular fields points to.  The same way if you had `x = { y: [ 1 ] };` and you did `x.y.push(2)` the array would be `[1, 2]`, or if you did `var y = x.y;` and then did `y.push(2)` that would also change the array to `[1, 2]`.  but if you then did `y = [ 3, 4 ]`, you are changing what y points to, not the actual array

Answer (score 0):

I notice in your code that you have this line and I wonder if its part of the problem.

`filterNode.prototype = Object.create(new processNode(nodeID, 'filter'));`

[Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) returns an object that has the prototype of `processNode` but not the prototype object itself. So you have a prototype equal to an object with another prototype inside of it.

```
filterNode {
    __proto__: processNode {
        __proto__: processNode.prototype
    }
}
```

This might be attributing to your reference issues.